# How to create cocoa gesture event

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a problem: how can I create gesture event by code, (rotate, magnify or swipe...), I don't want to use it to zoom or rotate a specific image or something like that, I want to create gesture event like scroll event create by `CGEventRef cgEvent = CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent(NULL, kCGScrollEventUnitLine, wheelCount, yScroll, xScroll);`

`CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, cgEvent);`

Thanks

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this??? I am struggling with a similar problem a couple of days already, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not all events have "shortcut" creation functions (like CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent, CGEventCreateMouseEvent, and CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent), so you have to create an empty event and then set the fields manually using the CGEventSet* functions.

The gesture-related events only have public constants for the Cocoa API level. For example, while NSLeftMouseDragged == kCGEventLeftMouseDragged == NX_LMOUSEDRAGGED == 6, NSEventTypeMagnify == 30 doesn't have any equivalent kCGEventMagnify or NX_MAGNIFY.

Also, the way gesture events work is a bit tricky; if you don't send the proper sequence of mouse/trackpad events, gesture, gesture begin/end, and specific-gesture events, it won't work.

There's not much documentation on which fields each event type needs; the easiest way to find out is to first create an event tap that logs everything, then generate the events you want and see what gets logged. In fact, you probably want to also log an NSEvent global monitor (log both the NSEvent itself and its underlying cgEvent).

Comment: This is way too vague. What exactly did you try, what result did you expect, what result did you get, and what example do you want?

Comment: :Sorry about the vague, I want to create Magnify event, so can you give me an example.

Comment: "gesture events work is a bit tricky;..." do you know the trick? do you have an example?

Comment: No, I don't have the trick for each gesture memorized, but I explained how to figure them out in the last paragraph: create an event tap that logs everything, and see what gets logged. Try to reproduce the same events and see what gets logged. PS, why did you downvote a months-old answer that you apparently didn't even read all the way through?

Comment: How to create this Event Tap and log. How to set Magnification or roatation on this events.